# Most efficient way to fetch model data from a relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

My `Message` model has many `MessageAttachment`

Following code:

```
$message = Message::find(1);

return $message->attachments;
```

Outputs:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "message_id": 1,
        "attachable_id": 1,
        "attachable_type": "Item",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "message_id": 1,
        "attachable_id": 1,
        "attachable_type": "Photo",
    }
]
```

Now, while this is all great, I'd like a way to fetch the model, the `MessageAttachment` is referring to (i.e. Photo, or Item). Something like:

```
return $message->attachments[0]->attachable; // outputs the Item 1 model
```

This is where I get stuck. How would you do that, in a clean and simple way, using above structure, or something similar?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Laravel's DB layer but my experience of framework DB layers in general has led me to believe that the most efficient way is to bypass the DB layer entirely and use a hand-crafted SQL query.  Also, without knowing your table structure it's difficult to answer this question in a meaningful way.  Please provide your schema.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
$messages = Message::find(1);

foreach($messages as $key => $value){
   $model = $value->attachable;
   $array[$key] = $model::find($value->attachable_id);
}

dd($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple. The solution:

```
class Message extends \Eloquent {
    public function attachments() {
        return $this->hasMany('MessageAttachment');
    }
}

class MessageAttachment extends \Eloquent {
    public function attachable() {
        return $this->morphTo();
    } 
}
```

Doing:

```
$message = Message::find(1);
$message->attachments[0]->attachable; // returns the model
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to fetch the items directly with the realtions. You can do this like this:

```
Messages::with('attachments', 'attachments.photo')->get();
```

Here photo is a relation of attachments. All relations will be fetched. If you have a single message you can access the relation by:

```
$message->attachments->first()->photo
```